# Default return value for Collectors.toMap

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, collectors

If we image, we have a object called person and person looks like the follwing:

```
class Person {
    int id;
    String name;
    String country
    // ...
    // getter/setter
}
```

And we have a `List` of `Person` objects and we want to "convert" it to a map. We can use the following:

```
Map<Long, List<Person>> collect = personList.stream().
    collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, p -> p));
```

But it is possible to return a default value for the valuemapper and change the type of the valuemapper?

I thought on something like that:

```
Map<Long, List<Person>> collect = 
     personList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId, 0));
```

but with this i get the following error `is not applicable for the arguments`

I have a workaround but i think it's not really pretty.

```
Map<Long, Object> collect2 = personList.stream().
    collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, pe -> {
            return 0;
    }));
```

Comment: Why use groupingBy? Doesn't each Person have a unique id? What are you grouping here?

Comment: Yes you right. Sorry, my mistkae, because i have in my ide a other object but before there come questions about what that object is and make etc. i decided to use a "allrounder" for this example. i change it.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want to achieve. What do you want the map to contain: give an example with 3 or 4 persons, and the resulting map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to map every ID of each person to the same value, that's exactly what you need to do, although you can simplify it by writing `Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, pe -> 0)`.